# Two way databinding does't work with multiple check boxes dynamically loaded in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem in managing dynamically loaded checkboxes from a dataset in React.
(I'm using React with only functional component and hooks with reactstrap library)
This is the dataset:

```
[
    {
       "expertiseAreaId": 1,
       "descriptionEng": "Analysis and Mapping",
       "descriptionFra": "Analyse et cartographie",
       "checked": false
    },
            {
       "expertiseAreaId": 1,
       "descriptionEng": "Strategic planning",
       "descriptionFra": "Planification stratégique",
       "checked": false
    },
            {
       "expertiseAreaId": 1,
       "descriptionEng": "Project/Proposal Design",
       "descriptionFra": "Projet/Proposition de projet",
       "checked": false
    },
    ....
]
```

Dataset is contained inside **expertiseAreasData**. I use another state variable (**expertiseAreaIds**) to store the booleans that will be read in the checked property of the checkboxes (Input type="checkbox")

```
    const [expertiseAreaIds, setExpertiseAreaIds] = useState([false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]);
    const [expertiseAreasData, setExpertiseAreasData] = useState([]);
```

Here is the JSX:

```
                    <br /><Label>Area of Expertise <span style={{ color: "red" }}>*</span></Label>
                <FormGroup row className="my-0" style={{ paddingLeft: "20px" }}>
                    <Col xs="12" sm="10" lg="10">

                        {expertiseAreasData.length > 0 ? expertiseAreasData.map((data, idx) => (<Fragment key={data.expertiseAreaId}><FormGroup check inline style={{ marginTop: "8px" }}>
                            <Input  className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked={expertiseAreaIds[idx]} onChange={() => onChangeExpertiseAreas(idx)} />
                            {language.toUpperCase() === "EN" && <Label className="form-check-label" check >{data.descriptionEng}</Label>}
                            {language.toUpperCase() === "FR" && <Label className="form-check-label" check >{data.descriptionFra}</Label>}
                        </FormGroup><br /></Fragment>)) : <span>No data loaded.</span>
                        }
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup><br />
```

When I call the onChangeExpertiseAreas event I update both expertiseAreaIds and expertiseAreasData

```
    const onChangeExpertiseAreas = (idx) => {
        var data = expertiseAreaIds;
        var value = data[idx];

        data[idx] = !value;
        setExpertiseAreaIds(data);

        var dt = expertiseAreasData;
        var element = dt[idx];
        element.checked = !value;
        dt[idx] = element;

        setExpertiseAreasData([]);
        setExpertiseAreasData(dt);
}
```

When I check the checkbox the status updates correctly, but the JSX is not updated and I always display the checkboxes at false (initial status).
I hope someone else has had my same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating data/state which is causing this issue. You always need to assign a new reference to a state value in order to trigger re-render.

Do this

```
const onChangeExpertiseAreas = (idx) => {
    var data = [...expertiseAreaIds]; // make a copy of array, change the reference
    var value = data[idx];

    data[idx] = !value;
    setExpertiseAreaIds(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, that was the problem! I arrived at the solution a little while ago. Thanks for the explanation. I post my new code:

State variable:

```
const [expertiseAreasData, setExpertiseAreasData] = useState([]);
```

JSX:

```
                    <br /><Label>Area of Expertise <span style={{ color: "red" }}>*</span></Label>
                <FormGroup row className="my-0" style={{ paddingLeft: "20px" }}>
                    <Col xs="12" sm="10" lg="10">

                        {expertiseAreasData.length > 0 ? expertiseAreasData.map((data, idx) => (<Fragment key={data.expertiseAreaId}><FormGroup check inline style={{ marginTop: "8px" }}>
                            <Input  className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked={data.checked} onChange={() => onChangeExpertiseAreas(idx)} />
                            {language.toUpperCase() === "EN" && <Label className="form-check-label" check >{data.descriptionEng}</Label>}
                            {language.toUpperCase() === "FR" && <Label className="form-check-label" check >{data.descriptionFra}</Label>}
                        </FormGroup><br /></Fragment>)) : <span>No data loaded.</span>
                        }
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup><br />
```

onChange event:

```
const onChangeExpertiseAreas = (idx) => {
    var value = expertiseAreasData[idx].checked;
    expertiseAreasData[idx].checked = !value;
    setExpertiseAreasData([...expertiseAreasData]);
}
```